# Why do I have two OS X Catalina volumes?

Tags: catalina

This:

[image]

And this:

[image]

Should I be concerned?  Should I remove one?

Comment: No - the system is on a separate, read-only volume.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is perfectly normal for Catalina; it is for security reasons. Macintosh HD has the OS. It is a read-only volume separate from other files on your Mac. Your personal files and data are stored in the Macintosh HD - Data. See [this Apple support page](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT210650) for more details.